# How to set active menu links under 'My Account' in Magento 2 frontend Customer Section

Tags: magento, hyperlink, magento2, account

I've got a custom module extending the customer account section.  I've added a new link called 'My Uploads'.  This link appears at the bottom of the My Account links sidebar.  On the index page, the 'My Uploads' link is bolded and not selectable.  However on my child pages none of the links are bolded or selectable.  I am searching how to keep the same link functionality in my custom module (i.e. all parent and child pages show the same sidebar link as active.) _SetActiveMenu appears to only be a method accessible in admin controllers so I really don't know any way to do this.  Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. It sounds like you've added a new link to the Admin Console. That would lead an experienced Magento developer to believe you've setup your own custom controller and controller action for the link. However, your question text indicates you don't have access to _setActiveMenu.  If you don't have a custom controller, how have you setup these new links?

Comment: Alan, I have also added a new link to the Admin Console but that's not what I'm referring to at the moment. I'm talking about the front-end customer account / my account section (The area you must be logged in to view). Some of those links being 'Account Information', 'Address Book', etc. I've added a new link called 'My Uploads' in my custom upload.xml config. The link shows up fine; I'm just trying to figure out how to keep it's state as 'ACTIVE' for all pages. If you navigate through the 'Account Information' pages, that link will remain active, etc. I hope that clarifies it a little.

Comment: Ah, mis-understood the question.  As you were.

Comment: Do you know of where I should be looking to figure this out?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you want to add a link in Customers "My Account" Sidebar. So, `navigation.php` which is available in /app/code/local/themename/customer/block/account/navigation.php controling those links. There are few function inside the file, some of them :

```
public function isActive($link)  
{
if (empty($this->_activeLink)) {
    $this->_activeLink = $this->getAction()->getFullActionName('/');
}
if ($this->_completePath($link->getPath()) == $this->_activeLink) {
    return true;
}
return false;
} 


public function setActive($path)
{
    $this->_activeLink = $this->_completePath($path);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I've already created the link, I just need to keep its state ACTIVE through the parent and children pages as the user navigates.

Comment: This is what `setActive` method needed for. You can call it from layouts, see http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts or from your controller. For the hints search in existing layouts for `action method="setActive"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within your layout.
Example for a link named 'changepassword':

```
<mycompany_changepassword_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Change Password Page</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/form_edit" name="mycompany_changepassword" template="mycompany/changepassword.phtml">
            <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="setActive"><path>changepassword</path></action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </reference>
</mycompany_changepassword_index_index>
```

Comment: Magento2.3.0 give error of 
"1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'path': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 1070"

Comment: Oh @MShoaibQureshi, my answer is just only for Magento 1.